# Papaparse proper encoding for strange characters

Tags: javascript, papaparse

I am trying to read strange characters from a .csv file using Papaparse.

Here is an example of some of the strange characters: ‡,œ,‰,Ž,etc

When I read these with papaparse I get: �,�,�, etc regardless of if printed to console or into a .csv/.txt file.

I've tried setting my papaparse config variable to various encoding types with no success.  I would like these characters to stay the same in console print out and when written to file.

Comment: I'm not great with encodings, but it would be helpful if you state what you tried already and what the input is.

Comment: Another approach is to review authoring of the CSV file. Saving it to disk with  UTF-8 encoding may even solve the problem.

Comment: @Traktor53 I used Numbers on Mac to resave as .csv in UTF-8.  Then all the characters read correctly.  Thank you.

Comment: Please consider posting an answer including how you needed to configure papaparse encoding  or whether it worked by default - personally I have no idea!. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by:

1. Opening the .csv file in Numbers (OSX)
2. File > Export to > CSV > Advanced Options > Unicode (UTF-8)
3. In papaparse config var set encoding: "utf-8"